# SQl script to add value of one field to another field

Tags: sql

I need to combine the value of 1 field to another in the table.

Can someone help with the script please?

So for example if there is 5 in loc 1 and 5 in loc 2, then I want the end result to be 10 in location 1.

Thanks =)

Comment: Please show us table structure and desired output.  Your question, as it stands now, is not very clear.

Comment: wellcome to StackOverflow. please make your question more clear: add tables definition, example data and your tries

Comment: Update query is the way to go, you can check for it's syntax on oracle docs if you're new to oracle, very simple though.

Answer (score 1):

Really straightforward.

```
Update MyTableName set Location1 = Location1 + Location2
 /* where SomeCondition */;
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS 
USING UPDATE QUERY

```
UPDATE YourTableName 
SET Location1 = CASE Location1 WHEN Location1 !='' THEN Location1 ELSE 0 END   
 + CASE Location2 WHEN Location2 !='' THEN Location2 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

do u want to do like this ?

```
UPDATE  MTN
SET     MTN.loc = MTN.loc + MAT.loc
FROM    MyTableName AS MTN
        INNER JOIN MyAnotherTable AS MAT ON MAT.id = MTN.id
```

Comment: Product specific answer, to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this is for!

Answer (score 0):

Below query can give the required result.

```
Update Table_Name set location1 = coalesce(location1,0) + coalesce(location2,0);
```

Here coalesce is used in case if location1 or location2 is NULL then the addition result will be NULL.